# Hiding .php extension through .htaccess works fine, but not for one page

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to hide the .php file extension, it's working fine, but one page doesn't. All the files are in the root. When I try to visit the gastenboek (guestbook) I get a 404 error page. Some files of the guestbook are in a folder, like messages, send and captcha. But the main file of that page (Gastenboek.php) is in the root. There is another page, the forum, this is also in a folder, but that page is working just fine. How is it possible that the Gastenboek doesn't show up, and the forum does? What am I doing wrong? This is the code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^slotraceclub.nl$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.slotraceclub.nl/$1 [R=301,L]

# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
</IfModule>
```